# Изображение с текстом, созданное с помощью php, отображается по разному

Tags: php

Заметил такую проблему. Есть код, который создает картинку с текстом на php. Тестировал все на Open Server, потом, когда загрузил на хостинг заметил, что текст отличается, хотя код один и тот же.

Сам код:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    // Создание изображения
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(1100, 750);

    // Создание цветов
    $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 81, 163, 36);

    // Путь к шрифту
    $font = './fonts/century-gothic-bold-italic.ttf';

    $size = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
        $size += 35;
        imagettftext($im, 8 + $i, 0, 25, $size, $color, $font, 'Test text [abcdefgh]');
    }

    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Вот изображение с Open Server:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это с хостинга:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-первых присутствуют небольшие пробелы между буквами. И так же шрифт на второй картинке более жирный. Больше всего это заметно на мелком тексте. Из-за чего может быть такая проблема?

Решил ещё дополнительно проверить на другом хостинге, разница с Open Server тоже есть, в небольших пробелах между буквами. Но текст не жирный, как на втором примере. А для меня это принципиально, так как я использую мелкий текст в своем коде.

Comment: И в чем вопрос?

Comment: Написал же, из-за чего может быть такая проблема?

Comment: может разные настройки графической библиотеки на хостинге и локалке..